# Pl Sql sysdate iterate over entire week

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for suggestions/best practices for one of the Pl Sql issue which I have to resolve , I have to run a weekly proc which will iterate over entire week for each day , now I just wondering how do I make sure that my to/from date covers
each day of the week , lets take an example of the week ending on 11/08/2015.
I have to get data 11/02, 11/03,11/04/,11/05/,11/06,11/07,11/08 , so my from and to date should be given in such a way that my proc can iterate over all week for each day .

I think I have to provide more clarity , my issue that I have to make sure that my from and to_date exactly capture data of from 12 AM night to 23:59 pm , that is for entire day , so criteria is something from_date=12 AM midnight , to_date=23:59 pm of the same day , It should happen for each day for entire week capturing whole week data on daily basis when i run my proc on sunday night that is once in a week.

Appreciate any inputs.

Comment: See [**Generate Date, Month Name, Week Number, Day number between two dates in Oracle SQL**](http://lalitkumarb.com/2015/04/15/generate-date-month-name-week-number-day-number-between-two-dates-in-oracle-sql/)

Comment: See my updated answer. I think it is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the **Row Generator** method to get all dates of the **current ISO week** (starts a **Monday** and ends a **Sunday**)

```
SQL> SELECT TRUNC(sysdate,'IW') + level - 1 the_date
  2  FROM dual
  3    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7
  4  /

THE_DATE
----------
02/11/2015
03/11/2015
04/11/2015
05/11/2015
06/11/2015
07/11/2015
08/11/2015

7 rows selected.
```

---

**UPDATE** OP actually wants to get the first and last second of the day as the **FROM_DATE** and **TO_DATE**.

You could add a day to the current day and then subtract one second using **+ 1 - (INTERVAL '1' SECOND)** to get the last second of the day.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW') + LEVEL - 1 FROM_DATE,
  2         TRUNC(SYSDATE,'IW') + LEVEL - 1 + 1 - (INTERVAL '1' SECOND) TO_DATE
  3  FROM dual
  4    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7
  5  /

FROM_DATE           TO_DATE
------------------- -------------------
11/02/2015 00:00:00 11/02/2015 23:59:59
11/03/2015 00:00:00 11/03/2015 23:59:59
11/04/2015 00:00:00 11/04/2015 23:59:59
11/05/2015 00:00:00 11/05/2015 23:59:59
11/06/2015 00:00:00 11/06/2015 23:59:59
11/07/2015 00:00:00 11/07/2015 23:59:59
11/08/2015 00:00:00 11/08/2015 23:59:59

7 rows selected.
```

Comment: You don't need to set the NLS_DATE_FORMAT. Your code is robust enough and doesn't do any unnecessary date to string to date conversions.

Comment: @Codo The date format was just to make sure the date would be displayed as `'dd/mm/yyyy` as my client settings are local specific to `DD-MON-YYYY`. I agree it is not a part of the query. Perhaps I should remove it to avoid confusion.

Comment: I think the solution you provided is close to what I am looking for ,  while I want to make sure that I take each combination  separately , so do I have to put in the cursor and iterate over it so that I can pass it in my query , while each row of the cursor will have one set of from/to dates   ?

Comment: @xslguy I have provided you everything you need. If you want to iterate over the 7 days, all you need is a cursor for loop using the above SQL. DO not use an explicit cursor, simply use a `cursor for loop`. For example, `For i in (select query I gave above) LOOP <do something> END LOOP;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple PL/SQL version. `TRUNC` gets the start of the period (in this case the week according to ISO). Then you can simply add the numbers 0 to 6 to get all the days in the week:

```
declare
  start_of_week date;
begin
  start_of_week := trunc(sysdate, 'IW');
  for i in 0..6 loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Date: ' || (start_of_week + i));
  end loop;
end;
/
```